# Need to know some advice about local storage in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

Hello dear stackoverflow users, I want to know your opinion on the use of local storage, now I will explain everything in more detail, I decided to use a color theme for my sidebar, that is, the user can change the color of the sidebar using radio buttons, it all looks like this

[image]

That is, when the theme changes, the color of the sidebar and content changes, the headers of the sidebar also change for such purposes, I decided to use local storage, but the problem is that in my opinion the code looks dirty too many lines there are repeated here is my actual code

**ThemeDoc.js**

```
export const CounterContext = createContext([]);

export default function ThemeDoc(props) {

    const [SideBarTheme, SetSideBarTheme] = useState(localStorage.getItem("SideBarKey"));
    const [PageContentTheme, SetPageContentTheme] = useState(localStorage.getItem("PageContentKey"));
    const [TextColor, SetTextColor] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TextColorKey')));
    const [SideBarBackground, SetSideBarBackground] = useState(localStorage.getItem("BgKey"));

    // SideBar Wallpapers
    const [SideBarBackgrounds,] = useState([
        {
            SideBarWallpaper: Bg,
        },
        {
            SideBarWallpaper: Pink,
        },
        {
            SideBarWallpaper: Anapa,
        },
    ])

    // Gradient Themes
    const [GradientThemes,] = useState([
        {
            SideBar: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(66, 116, 131, 1) 0%, rgba(69, 75, 88, 1) 100%)",
            PageContent: "linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(65,116,130,1) 0%, #353a4f 80%)",
            TextColor: "#dfdfdfb3",
            RadioButtonBackground: "linear-gradient(40deg, #51adff, #10f4a0)",
            RadioButtonBorderColor: "1px solid #33b7de",
        },
        {
            SideBar: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(146 93 116) 0%, rgb(71 75 88) 100%)",
            PageContent: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(147 99 123) 0%, rgb(55 58 80) 80%)",
            TextColor: "#dfdfdfb3",
            RadioButtonBackground: "linear-gradient(120deg,#ffb2b2 0,#f68084 100%)",
            RadioButtonBorderColor: "1px solid #ff8185fa",
        },
        {
            SideBar: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(96 110 150) 0%, rgb(69 75 88) 100%)",
            PageContent: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(94 110 149) 0%, rgb(53 58 80) 80%)",
            TextColor: "#dfdfdfb3",
            RadioButtonBackground: "linear-gradient(40deg, rgb(48 137 198), rgb(161 186 255))",
            RadioButtonBorderColor: "1px solid #818db0",
        },
    ])

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("SideBarKey", SideBarTheme, "PageContentKey", PageContentTheme);
        localStorage.setItem('TextColorKey', JSON.stringify(TextColor));

        localStorage.setItem("BgKey", SideBarBackground);
    })

    const ChangeSideBarWallpaper = (SideBarWallpaper) => {
        localStorage.setItem('BgKey', SideBarWallpaper);
        SetSideBarTheme(localStorage.removeItem("SideBarKey"));
        SetSideBarBackground(SideBarWallpaper);
    }

    const SideBarPageContent = (PageContent, SideBar, TextColor) => {
        localStorage.setItem('PageContentKey', PageContent, 'SideBarKey', SideBar);
        localStorage.setItem('TextColorKey', JSON.stringify(TextColor));

        SetPageContentTheme(PageContent);
        SetSideBarTheme(SideBar);
        SetTextColor(TextColor);
    }

    const gradientList = GradientThemes.map((gradTheme, index) => {
        return (
            <RadioButton
                key={index}
                style={{background: gradTheme.RadioButtonBackground, border: gradTheme.RadioButtonBorderColor}}
                className={"RadioButton_ThemeDoc"}
                name="group1"
                value="first"
                onChange={() => SideBarPageContent(gradTheme.PageContent, gradTheme.SideBar, gradTheme.TextColor)}
            />
        );
    })

    const SideBarWallpaperList = SideBarBackgrounds.map((theme, index) => {
        return (
            <img key={index} width={"52"} height={"42"} src={theme.SideBarWallpaper} className={"SideBar_Appearance_Select_Icon"}
                 onClick={() => ChangeSideBarWallpaper(theme.SideBarWallpaper)} alt={"Select Theme"} />
        );
    })

    return (
        <div className="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled">
            <CounterContext.Provider value={{
                SideBarValue: [SideBarTheme, SetSideBarTheme],
                PageContentValue: [PageContentTheme, SetPageContentTheme],
                TextColorValue: [TextColor, SetTextColor],
                SideBarWallpaperValue: [SideBarBackground, SetSideBarBackground],
            }}>
                <SideBar gradientList={gradientList} SideBarWallpaperList={SideBarWallpaperList} {...props} />
                <PageContent {...props} />
            </CounterContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

As you can see, besides using local storage, I use the React context then call and apply the desired value in the desired component. Here is an example using "TextColor" value in SideBarMenu component

**SideBarMenu.js**

```
const CourseTopic = styled.span`
  color: #582f35;
`;

export default function SideBarMenu(props) {

    const {TextColorValue} = React.useContext(CounterContext);
    const [TextColor,] = TextColorValue;

    return (
        <ul>
            {SidebarItems.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <React.Fragment key={index}>
                        {item.CourseTopic && (
                            <li className="header-menu">
                                <img style={{width: "22px", marginRight: "5px"}} src={Hashtag} alt=""/>
                                <CourseTopic style={{color: TextColor}}>{item.CourseTopic}</CourseTopic>
                            </li>
                        )}

                        ...
                    </React.Fragment>
                );
            })}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

That is, it turns out that for each style, for example, for the background or text, I create a separate hook, I don't know, maybe this is normal, if this is normal then tell me please, I want to know if my approach is really correct or not?

Comment: You can use ThemeProvider from styled component library and simply change the themes and apply multi themes more simply and cleaner. here is the address:
https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Comment: Thanks for the answer I would like to clarify in this case I have to use local storage as shown in my code I just need to save the change that the user made